# asp can't detect the checked item in datagridview

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview with ckeck column,my user can select the item via checked box so i add a checkbox column to my gridview:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="taminkonandeh" runat="server" CssClass="gv-list-company-col-edit" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True">
                                <Columns>
                                     <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="ChTaminKonande" runat="server" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                         </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="شماره " DataField="companyid" >
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv-list-company-header" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="gv-list-company-col" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="نام شرکت " DataField="companyname">
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv-list-company-header" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="gv-list-company-col" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="شماره ثبت " DataField="registrationNumber" >
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv-list-company-header" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="gv-list-company-col" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="شماره اقتصادی" DataField="noEconomic" >
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv-list-company-header" />
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="gv-list-company-col" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                </Columns>
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv-list-company-header" />
                                <RowStyle CssClass="gv-list-company-row"/>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

and my code behind is :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < taminkonandeh.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    CheckBox chinvi = (CheckBox)taminkonandeh.Rows[i].FindControl("ChTaminKonande");
                    if (chinvi != null)
                    {
                        if (chinvi.Checked)
                        {
                            Count++;
                            comid = taminkonandeh.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                            tblAnnouncePriceByCompany objanno = new tblAnnouncePriceByCompany();
                            objanno.letterId = objletter.letterId.ToString();
                            objanno.companyId = comid;
                            objanno.tenderId = Session["letterTenderId"].ToString();
                            db1.tblAnnouncePriceByCompanies.InsertOnSubmit(objanno);

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myalert",
                                                      "alert('تامین کننده  ای  انتخاب نشده است ')", true);
                        return;
                    }

            }
```

but "chinvi.Checked" condition is always false and i can't detect which checkboxs are selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation happens when you bind the gridview in pageload, and each postback rebinds it, removes posted value like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code to get datasource
    taminkonandeh.DataSource = myDataSource;
    taminkonandeh.DataBind();
}
```

You need to change it to :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Code to get datasource
        taminkonandeh.DataSource = myDataSource;
        taminkonandeh.DataBind();
    }
}
```